# Como recibir una imagen de un parámetro por URL?

Tags: java, android, json, recyclerview

Estoy pasando parámetros desde un recyclerview hacia otra actividad, el problema especifico es que se trae una URL la cual alberga una imagen, la cual estoy pasando a la otra actividad pero tengo problemas para presentarla en la actividad donde se reciben los parámetros traidos desde el recyclerview. se esta utilizando un pequeño servidor para imagen para almacenarlas al traerlas desde el Json.

Clase del RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<GetHotels> getDataAdapter;

ImageLoader imageLoader1;



public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetHotels> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewhotel, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {

    final GetHotels getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);


    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getLogo(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );

    Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getLogo(), imageLoader1);
    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());

    Viewholder.networkImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailBusinessActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Logo",getDataAdapter1.getLogo().toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
    public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
    public TextView Phone;

    public RatingBar start;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;
        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_h) ;
        start = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MyRating);

    }
}
```

}

Clase ServerImageParseAdapter.

```
public class ServerImageParseAdapter {

public static ServerImageParseAdapter SIAdapter;

public static Context context1;

public RequestQueue requestQueue1;

public ImageLoader Imageloader1;

public Cache cache1 ;

public Network networkOBJ ;

LruCache<String, Bitmap> LRUCACHE = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(30);

private ServerImageParseAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context1 = context;

    this.requestQueue1 = RQ();

    Imageloader1 = new ImageLoader(requestQueue1, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String URL) {

                    return LRUCACHE.get(URL);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                    LRUCACHE.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {

    return Imageloader1;
}

public static ServerImageParseAdapter getInstance(Context SynchronizedContext) {

    if (SIAdapter == null) {

        SIAdapter = new ServerImageParseAdapter(SynchronizedContext);
    }
    return SIAdapter;
}

public RequestQueue RQ() {

    if (requestQueue1 == null) {

        cache1 = new DiskBasedCache(context1.getCacheDir());

        networkOBJ = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

        requestQueue1 = new RequestQueue(cache1, networkOBJ);

        requestQueue1.start();
    }
    return requestQueue1;
}
```

}

La clase donde se reciben los parámetros del RecyclerView

```
public class DetailBusinessActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

//ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
private GoogleMap mMap;

String logo;
String Name = "";
String TypeBusiness = "";
String Adreess = "";
String Phone = "";
String Email = "";
String Web = "";
String lat = "";
String lon = "";
Double latD2, lonD2;

ImageView PhoneL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_business);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Otain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapasRes);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    logo = i.getStringExtra("Logo");
    Name = i.getStringExtra("Name");
    Adreess = i.getStringExtra("Adreess");
    TypeBusiness = i.getStringExtra("TypeBusiness");
    Phone = i.getStringExtra("Phone");
    Email = i.getStringExtra("Email");
    Web = i.getStringExtra("Web");
    lat = i.getStringExtra("Lat");
    lon = i.getStringExtra("Lng");


    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    TextView txtBusieness = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Busieness);
    TextView textAdreess = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Adreess);
    TextView textPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Phone);
    TextView textEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    TextView textWeb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Web);
    PhoneL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneL);

    PhoneL.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentcall = new Intent();
            intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Phone)); // set the Uri
            startActivity(intentcall);
        }
    });




    // Set results to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(Name);
    txtBusieness.setText(TypeBusiness);
    textAdreess.setText(Adreess);
    textPhone.setText(Phone);
    textEmail.setText(Email);
    textWeb.setText(Web);


   // ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Logo);
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
   // imageLoader.DisplayImage(logo, imgflag);



    latD2 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
    lonD2 = Double.parseDouble(lon);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng Hotels = new LatLng(latD2, lonD2);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Hotels).title(Name)
            .snippet(Adreess)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Hotels));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(latD2, lonD2), 12));


    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer estas enviando la imagen de esta forma:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailBusinessActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Logo",getDataAdapter1.getLogo().toString());
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Dentro de la clase `DetailBusinessActivity` recibes la imagen de esta forma:

```
logo = i.getStringExtra("Logo");
```

Asegura que sea una url de imagen valida, obten la referencia del ImageView donde se desplegará:

```
 ImageView imgLogo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Logo);
```

Puedes cargar facilmente la imagen mediante [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) :

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(logo).into(imgLogo);
```

---

Otra opción es usar Google [Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en), pero personalmente he encontrado bugs en algunos sistemas operativos.

Comment: Hermano muchísimas gracias por el dato de verdad me sirvió bastante para mi duda, ahora con ello puedo seguir trabajando.

Comment: Excelente César, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar **Glide**

Es una librería que te ayuda en las imágenes para desarrollo Android
te adjunto la forma que suelo utilizar..

```
public static void usarGlide(Context context, String rutaIcono, ImageView imageView) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(rutaIcono)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .crossFade()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.not_found)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

Entonces se necesita de 3 puntos importantes el `Context`, la ruta del ícono y el `ImageView` aparte de ello es opcional agregar `placeholder(R.drawable.not_found)` ya que esto ayudaría si es q la ruta del ícono no contiene nada, tendrías una imagen por defecto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el dato hermano.